# How to convert Mysql encoding utf8 to utf8mb4 in Rails project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding

I have a Rails 3.2 project using `Mysql 5.5.34`, with utf8 encoding. Now I found that with `utf8` encoding Mysql could not save unicode characters which represent emoji.

So is it OK for me to convert the whole database to use `utf8mb4` encoding that I found on the web that could hold 4 byte unicode include emoji?

Is all the information I have in the database covered by `utf8mb4` encoding? Will I face data loses if I do that?

Is there any way that Rails provide to do that?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I am kinda facing the same situation.. What did you end up doing?

Comment: @Hari Sorry for the late response. I've done that following this blog: http://blog.xdite.net/posts/2013/12/19/mysql-with-utf8mb4 . Unfortunately it's written in Chinese, would you try Google translate to see if it helps?

Comment: http://blog.arkency.com/2015/05/how-to-store-emoji-in-a-rails-app-with-a-mysql-database/

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just need to migrate the column you want to encode with utf8mb4.

```
execute("ALTER TABLE yourtablename MODIFY yourcolumnname TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;")
```

If you plan to migrate the data itself it might not be possible, since the common utf8 consists out of 3 byte chars and the utf8mb4 out of 4 byte. So you might already have corrupt data in your db.

Furthermore Rails 3.2 has an encoding issue within ActiveSupports JSON encoding. In case you plan to work with json and emojis, you will need to add a patch like the following (based on the solution in rails 4 https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb) or just simply upgrade to rails 4.

```
module ActiveSupport
  module JSON
    module Encoding
      class << self
        def escape(string)
          if string.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
            string = string.encode(::Encoding::UTF_8, :undef => :replace).force_encoding(::Encoding::BINARY)
          end
          json = string.gsub(escape_regex) { |s| ESCAPED_CHARS[s] }
          json = %("#{json}")
          json.force_encoding(::Encoding::UTF_8) if json.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
          json
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I did the alter table query above.. the smilies still end up as a bunch of question marks like this "????" .. Any idea?

Comment: Anything I should add to the answer?

Comment: @Hari What did you do to solve the database connection?